# Inbuilt files of expo getting unreadble and corrupted

Tags: react-native, expo

I am a noob in react-native development. Previously I only had expo-cli, then I came to know that react-native-cli is better so I installed that also. But later on i realised that react-native is not as easier as expo so i made a third app on expo again using expo init appname.[I tried uninstalling and installing expo again and again but could not find a solution of this bug. I also tried manually editing the AppEntry.Js file but wasted my time only.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Uhl.png) If any user find a solution please explain. I also have unanswered questions in django and hadoop. But no one from community even watch my question also. If admin of this site can view my question please suggest why my questions are not getting any answer

Comment: Please use VS Code Editor, also within editor install react-native tools. Easy way to develop,debug React native App. After completion of code u can use Expo for Testing purpose.

Comment: @pavankvch I am already using VScode. I am even able to develop 2-3 projects at a time but all of sudden when I am going with other app the inbuilt file emit.js becomes unreadable it says that it has no closing bracket but I cannot even read the Js file so that i can inspect and correct it